# The console isn't giving a response to user input. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I am making a pizza program that asks for the the user's choice of pizza, the size, the toppings and if they want delivery or not. However, I am facing a problem where I input something into the console as input but I don't receive any response. I have included the code.

**My Code:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Zayann's Pizza");
        Scanner myPizza = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What pizza would you like? 1) cheese 2) chicken 3) beef 4) veg-- Please enter number");
        String[] pizzaSize = {"6 inch", "9 inch", "12 inch", "15 inch", "20 inch"};
        String[] pizza = {"cheese","chicken","beef","veg"};
        String pizzaOrder = myPizza.nextLine();
        if (myPizza.equals(pizza[0])) {
            System.out.println("You have selected cheese");
            System.out.println("What size would you like? 6 inch, 9 inch, 12 inch, 15 inch,20 inch-- Please enter size");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Paste your code please, not image of it ;)

Comment: pizzaOrder is the Scanner, do you mean `pizzaOrder.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a Scanner (myPizza) with a String (pizza[0]).

And how @azro  say, please paste your code, not upload your image.

Answer (score 0):

You should not to compare a Scanner object with String，try the follow code：

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Zayann's Pizza");
        Scanner myPizza = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What pizza would you like? 1) cheese 2) chicken 3) beef 4) veg-- Please enter number");
        String[] pizzaSize = {"6 inch", "9 inch", "12 inch", "15 inch", "20 inch"};
        String[] pizza = {"cheese","chicken","beef","veg"};
        String pizzaOrder = myPizza.nextLine();
        if (pizzaOrder.equals(pizza[0])) {
            System.out.println("You have selected cheese");
            System.out.println("What size would you like? 6 inch, 9 inch, 12 inch, 15 inch,20 inch-- Please enter size");
            String pizzaEnterSize = myPizza.nextLine();
            if (pizzaEnterSize.equals(pizzaSize[0])) {
                System.out.println("You chose 6 inch size");
            }
        }
    }
```